# how to doing event intent in recyclerview adapter after interstitial ads closed?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, interstitial

I'm trying to show interstitial ads every two clicks in recyclerview item, it works but i ads show up after event intent start, what i want to do is ads showing before intent start, here's my code in recyclerview adapter. Could someone help me with this?

```
    int counter=1;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
        default:
            MenuItemViewHolder menuItemHolder = (MenuItemViewHolder) holder;
            DafAdapter menuItem = (DafAdapter) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
            //final String urut = menuItem.getUrut();
            final String judul = menuItem.getTitle();
            final String description = menuItem.getContent();

            // Add the menu item details to the menu item view.
            menuItemHolder.menuItemUrut.setText(menuItem.getUrut());
            menuItemHolder.menuItemtitle.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
            //menuItemHolder.menuItemDescription.setText(menuItem.getDescription()); //ditutup supaya tidak muncul di recyclerview

            //======================================================

            menuItemHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(counter==2){
                        MainActivity.ShowAd();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ContentActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("judul", judul);
                        intent.putExtra("deskripsi", description);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        counter=1;
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ContentActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("judul", judul);
                        intent.putExtra("deskripsi", description);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            });
            //======================================================
    }
}
```

and ads showing like this,
[image]

**and what i want is :**

[image]

Comment: Start the activity in callback onAdClosed

Comment: onAdClosed is in MainActivity and startActivity intent using put.Extra in recyclerview adapter different file java class, how to call it in MainActivity using intent.putExtra from ecyclerview adapter?

Comment: Where is your data set? How MainActivity and RecyclerView interact? It is a design issue, many approaches to your problem.

Comment: actually this event is in every fragment, i'm using mainActivity to create "public static void ShowAd()"

so i can call it in recyclerview adapter to show ads.

Comment: how to call/access this 


" final String judul = menuItem.getTitle();
final String description = menuItem.getContent();  "


from adapter into fragment? help me please